# Find out which item in the ListView invoked the context menu in Android

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

How can I find out which item in the ListView is clicked to invoke the context menu? Can I get the index (or something) for the clicked list item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the ListView has to be registered for the context menu.

Here is the code that I used:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    ListView lv = (ListView) v;
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    String contextMenuInvoked = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(acmi.position);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Edit");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Log.d("ListView click", "clicked index is:" + position);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm looking for a method to use inside of onContextItemSelected that can give the item which was clicked in the ListView to invoke the contextview which I'm in now.

Comment: Please modify your question there you asked for index of clicked list item. Also add some relevant code block.